# octopress cannot route public

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

I've been trying to learn octopress, so I need to deploy it on heroku. I did at last point but I don't see my website.

When I run

```
heroku open
```

I face this problem on my web browser

> Sorry, I cannot find/

because of

```
  not_found do
    send_sinatra_file('404.html') {"Sorry, I cannot find #{request.path}"}
  end
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 16):

From your command line, open the `.gitignore` listing (located within your repo) and remove the following line, `public`.

Next `rake generate` and push it to Heroku.

That should do it.

Comment: This worked for me - had to git add . to include the public files, git commit, and then push up to heroku

Comment: Thanks for this, it was not in the Octopress documentation... seems like quite an emission.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I am going to toss this up on the Octopress bug I posted about it.  Cheers and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Yeah that was it for me too.  Why on earth this is the default setting AND not in the docs is beyond me, but thank you!  Saved me much gnashing of the teeth and hair pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default '/' route set up?  It would appear not...

Answer (score 0):

You can read a related pull request: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/pull/113